# Get inside all images in array using jquery?

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<div class="cms-featuredbox">
  <div class="category-title">
      <img alt="" src="http://localhost/project/lulupu/skin/frontend/default/lulupu/images/featured_products_title.png">
  </div>
<div class="listing-type-grid catalog-listing">
<div id="slider" style="width: 663px; height: 325px; overflow: hidden;">
<ul style="width: 1989px; margin-left: -625.437px;">
 <li class = "test" style="margin-left: -663px; float: left;"><div class="tab2" id="featured-product">
            <div class="featured-product-top"></div>
            <div class="featured-bg" style="width:310px;float:left;text-align:center;">
                    <div><a title="The Magnet Source&trade; Magnet Tape 1/2&quot;x 30&quot;" href="http://localhost/project/lulupu/index.php/featured/the-magnet-sourcetm-magnet-tape-1-2-x-30.html">
                        <img width="260" height="260" alt="The Magnet Source&trade; Magnet Tape 1/2&quot;x 30&quot;" src="http://localhost/project/lulupu/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/260x260/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/a/magent.jpg">
                    </a>  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="featured-product-body">
        <div style="width:322px;float:right;padding:6px;">
                    <div class="protilte">The Magnet Source&trade; Magnet Tape 1/2"x 30"</div>
                    <p>Magnetic products. Tape 1/2"x 30"- Gives you a quick and easy way to add a magnet to lightweight craft projects. Easy as 1-2-3, cut to length, peel off adhesive liner and apply to craft project. It cuts easily with scissors.</p>
                    <a title="The Magnet Source&trade; Magnet Tape 1/2&quot;x 30&quot;" href="http://localhost/project/lulupu/index.php/featured/the-magnet-sourcetm-magnet-tape-1-2-x-30.html" class="knowmore">Know More</a>
             </div></div>
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                            <div class="featured-product-btm"></div>
                </div>
</li>
<li style="float: left;"><div class="tab1" id="featured-product">
            <div class="featured-product-top"></div>
            <div class="featured-bg" style="width:310px;float:left;text-align:center;">
                    <div><a title="VersaMark Watermark Ink Stamp Pad Large Dazzle Frost" href="http://localhost/project/lulupu/index.php/featured/versamark-watermark-ink-stamp-pad-large-dazzle-frost.html">
                        <img width="260" height="260" alt="VersaMark Watermark Ink Stamp Pad Large Dazzle Frost" src="http://localhost/project/lulupu/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/260x260/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/r/frostdazzle_0.jpg">
                    </a>  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="featured-product-body">
        <div style="width:322px;float:right;padding:6px;">
                    <div class="protilte">VersaMark Watermark Ink Stamp Pad Large Dazzle Frost</div>
                    <p>Making your mark has never been easier! VersaMark&trade; watermark/resist ink gives you unique options for the distinction you've been looking for. Simply stamp your image onto paper and explore the possibilities of watermarking your own stationary or subtle tone-on-tone designs. Plus, VersaMark&trade; performs well as a resist ink. VersaMark&trade; - the versatility is in the ink! Refill available. Large Dazzle Frost- Dazzle combines all the great qualities of the original VersaMark&trade; with added shimmer to give your paper projects an easy touch of elegance.</p>
                    <a title="VersaMark Watermark Ink Stamp Pad Large Dazzle Frost" href="http://localhost/project/lulupu/index.php/featured/versamark-watermark-ink-stamp-pad-large-dazzle-frost.html" class="knowmore">Know More</a>
             </div></div>
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                            <div class="featured-product-btm"></div>
                </div></li>
                                    <li style="float: left;"><div class="tab2" id="featured-product">
            <div class="featured-product-top"></div>
            <div class="featured-bg" style="width:310px;float:left;text-align:center;">
                    <div><a title="The Magnet Source&trade; Magnet Tape 1/2&quot;x 30&quot;" href="http://localhost/project/lulupu/index.php/featured/the-magnet-sourcetm-magnet-tape-1-2-x-30.html">
                        <img width="260" height="260" alt="The Magnet Source&trade; Magnet Tape 1/2&quot;x 30&quot;" src="http://localhost/project/lulupu/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/260x260/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/a/magent.jpg">
                    </a>  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="featured-product-body">
        <div style="width:322px;float:right;padding:6px;">
                    <div class="protilte">The Magnet Source&trade; Magnet Tape 1/2"x 30"</div>
                    <p>Magnetic products. Tape 1/2"x 30"- Gives you a quick and easy way to add a magnet to lightweight craft projects. Easy as 1-2-3, cut to length, peel off adhesive liner and apply to craft project. It cuts easily with scissors.</p>
                    <a title="The Magnet Source&trade; Magnet Tape 1/2&quot;x 30&quot;" href="http://localhost/project/lulupu/index.php/featured/the-magnet-sourcetm-magnet-tape-1-2-x-30.html" class="knowmore">Know More</a>
             </div></div>
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                            <div class="featured-product-btm"></div>
                </div>
</li>
<li style="float: left;"><div class="tab1" id="featured-product">
            <div class="featured-product-top"></div>
            <div class="featured-bg" style="width:310px;float:left;text-align:center;">
                    <div><a title="VersaMark Watermark Ink Stamp Pad Large Dazzle Frost" href="http://localhost/project/lulupu/index.php/featured/versamark-watermark-ink-stamp-pad-large-dazzle-frost.html">
                        <img width="260" height="260" alt="VersaMark Watermark Ink Stamp Pad Large Dazzle Frost" src="http://localhost/project/lulupu/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/260x260/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/f/r/frostdazzle_0.jpg">
                    </a>  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="featured-product-body">
        <div style="width:322px;float:right;padding:6px;">
                    <div class="protilte">VersaMark Watermark Ink Stamp Pad Large Dazzle Frost</div>
                    <p>Making your mark has never been easier! VersaMark&trade; watermark/resist ink gives you unique options for the distinction you've been looking for. Simply stamp your image onto paper and explore the possibilities of watermarking your own stationary or subtle tone-on-tone designs. Plus, VersaMark&trade; performs well as a resist ink. VersaMark&trade; - the versatility is in the ink! Refill available. Large Dazzle Frost- Dazzle combines all the great qualities of the original VersaMark&trade; with added shimmer to give your paper projects an easy touch of elegance.</p>
                    <a title="VersaMark Watermark Ink Stamp Pad Large Dazzle Frost" href="http://localhost/project/lulupu/index.php/featured/versamark-watermark-ink-stamp-pad-large-dazzle-frost.html" class="knowmore">Know More</a>
             </div></div>
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                            <div class="featured-product-btm"></div>
                </div>
</li>
</ul>
            </div><ol id="controls">
<li id="controls1" class="current"><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="0">1</a></li><li id="controls2" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="1">2</a></li></ol>
</div></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
var tn_array = $("#slider ul li img").map(function() {

  return $(this).attr("src");
});

for (var i=0; i<tn_array.length; i++) {
  alert(tn_array[i]);
}
```

I didnt get images array?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/9za5Q/

Comment: Your code worked just fine when I tested it on [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/ "jsfiddle") with jQuery 1.10.1 : your loop returns each image src attribute as they are saved in the array you declared. What are you trying to obtain, and what output did you get ?

Comment: i for get to add get()... now its working

Answer (score 3):

Use `.each()` to iterate through each element found.

For example:

```
$( "#slider ul li img" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $(this).src() );
});
```

edit:Your array map also works fine i think your are iterating before document is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tn_array = $("#slider ul li img").map(function() {

    return $(this).attr("src");
  });

  for (var i=0; i<tn_array.length; i++) {
    alert(tn_array[i]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you need use .get(), because >map() returns a jQuery object not an array

```
var tn_array = $("#slider ul li img").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("src");
}).get();
```

Comment: Should still work without the `get()` though: http://jsfiddle.net/G86Zx/ No idea why the OP's doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var tn_array = [];
$( "#slider ul li img" ).each(function() {
  tn_array.push($(this).attr("src"));
});
```